# When should I link words and when not?

Tags: grammar

Is this any rule for this?

I'm thinking aboutphrases like "filepath" vs. "file path", or "onground" vs "on ground".

Are any of these better than the second? Or can I use both?

Comment: *Filepath* belongs to various computer languages. *File path* is English.

Sorry, I've never heard of *onground* or *on ground*

Comment: Which computer languages? It's concerns computer science, I know, but I see it both as "file path" - two words, and "filepath" - one word. Isn't "filepath" correct word in English?

Comment: Please consider where you see it both as "file path" - two words, and "filepath" - one word…

No; "filepath" isn't a correct word in English.

There is no hard or fast rule but basically words such as, for instance, lamppost start life as two clearly distinct words, lamp post, then become hyphenated, pamp-post, then combine to become a single word, lamppost.

I suggest that in English, the path of the file is far too new a concept even to have become file-path - adjectival use doesn't count; we're talking about nouns - let alone filepath.

Comment: I see it written as one word (all lower case) in computer code all the time.  Nevertheless, it is not in any dictionary, and does not appear to be an English word at all.

Comment: @cowlinator the same case for me ;) but do you mean filepath or onground?