# "Filepath" or "file path"?

Tags: compounds, computing, spacing

> A [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)), the general form of the name of a file or directory, specifies
>   a unique location in a file system.

"Filename" is a compound, but how about "filepath"/"file path"? "Filepath" seems incorrect to me, but as stated above, a related compound exists.

Comment: If you'd lived centuries ago, you'd probably have insisted on the two-word form ***foot path***. Or you could have compromised with ***foot-path*** so people could gradually get used to modern ***footpath*** through an intermediate format.

Comment: I've converted my earlier comment to an answer, after trying to find any sort of formal documentation of the distinction and failing.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389432/when-should-i-link-words-and-when-not.

Answer (score 25):

This is a technical term, used in discussing computer data storage. Both forms, *filepath* and *file path*, are used, but which one is used is often dependent on context. While I can’t find any specific reference for usage in context, my experience has been that *filepath*, as an unhyphenated compound word, is generally used when discussing it as an entity (e.g., “You’ll need to set the *filepath* before writing out any data.”), but *file path*, as two words, is generally used when referring to a particular attribute of a file (e.g., “The *file path* of the JonesCo proposal is C:\Users\jsmith123\Documents\Proposals\JonesCo.docx.”

Comment: This is a gem explanation that helps me elucidate my own intuition. I've found it invaluable when writing code, to be able to explain to others why I sometimes wrote filepath versus file_path. At some subconscious level, I knew why I was doing this, but I couldn't consciously process why.

Comment: I have trouble understanding how the filepath of the JonesCo proposal is different from its file path.  
  
Maybe you also mean this?  
Use filepath when it is the whole object of the sentence.  
Use file path when it is _part_ of the complete object of the sentence.

Comment: @eisenpony - Don't try to apply strict grammatical interpretation to terms of art/jargon from an industry. A _filepath_ is an entity, independent of any particular file; a _file path_ is an attribute of a particular file (even if we're not specifying _what_ particular file we're talking about). In a program, I can set a _filepath_, and then use that filepath to create a new file, whose _file path_ attribute is the contents of the _filepath_ entity I created and stored a value in earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The general trend is how FumbleFingers described.
If in doubt, I type (or copy & paste) an expression as a single word into dictionary.com. It may tell me it knows that word. It may return it with a hyphen. If it doesn't recognise it, I then write it as two words.
That's the only way I know to be consistent in always writing words the same way.

Comment: And your answer to “Filepath” or “file path” is..?

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/filepath
Answer: No results found for filepath